# Disable snapshotting ("save" setting) on running instance

Tags: redis

How can you disable snapshotting on a running Redis instance?

You can disable the "save" setting in the Redis configuration by commenting out the "save" lines. E.g.,

```shell
#save 900 1
#save 300 10
#save 60 10000
```

However, Redis lacks a command to reload its configuration without restarting. How can I remove the "save" settings from a running instance of Redis? There seems to be no CONFIG DEL or CONFIG UNSET commands, and I didn't see anything related to this in [CONFIG GET](http://redis.io/commands/config-get) or [CONFIG SET](http://redis.io/commands/config-set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try inspecting the value of the "save" setting, you'll notice it's a single string value containing each *save point*:

```
> CONFIG GET save
1) "save"
2) "900 1 300 10 60 10000"
```

According to the Redis configuration file [redis.conf](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf):

> It is also possible to remove all the previously configured save
>   points by adding a save directive with a single empty string argument
>   like in the following example:
>
> ```
> save ""
> ```

So to disable snapshotting you can remove those *save points* by setting its value to an empty string:

```
> CONFIG SET save ""
OK
> CONFIG GET save
1) "save"
2) ""
```